# Decode Base64 image from MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, base64

I am storing my image as BLOB in an online MySQL database by encoding the image using Base64. I don't have a problem with saving. But I can't retrieve the images from the server. They appear to be broken. I believe this is happening because it's not being decoded.

I tried manually uploading a couple of photos to the server, and they are retrieved properly since they are not encoded. This is the code I'm using to retrieve the image. Can someone please tell me how to decode the image?

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","un","pw") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("datab",$db) or die(mysql_error()); 
$userId = $_GET['eid']; 
$query = "SELECT image FROM event WHERE eid='$userId'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
$photo = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
header('Content-Type:image/png;base64'); 
echo $photo['image']; 
?>
```

Comment: Base64 is not an encryption algorithm. It's an encoding. To do encryption, you need some kind of key which is absent for default Base64.

Comment: Okay my bad. Thanks for pointing out. Anyway, how can I decode? @ArtjomB.

Comment: Start by fixing the real issues at hand here. That **SQL Injection** will cause a lot of troubles for you if you don't fix it.

Comment: @Darren,which one are you talking about? I'm sorry but I'm a beginner at all this. Can you tell me a way to decode the image and show it?

Comment: Your code `SELECT image FROM event WHERE eid='$userId'` is injectable. You need to sanitize `$userId`.

Comment: For now how can I get the decoded image? Once I figure it out, I'll look into this security issue you're pointing out @Darren

Answer (score 0):

First, please note that mysql syntax is outdated and totally deprecated ! Please use mysqli or PDO instead !

Then, following your code, you just have to call you image in your html file, like that :

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, <?php echo $photo['image']; ?>">
```

Comment: actually, I want to test it by using `server/image.php?eid=351` and not HTML. So I guess when echoing itself, the image should be decoded

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgraded you to mysqli and show you how to prepare statement and execute it. (Full Disclosure, i havent written mysqli code in a very long time so it might be wrong)
2. if image doesnt exist, a 404 not found status is sent and the script dies. else image is `base64_decode`'d and output to browser.

---

```
$db = new mysqli( 'localhost' , 'un' , 'pw', 'datab' );
$userId = intval( $_GET['eid'] ); //convert it to an int.
$stmt = $db->prepare( 'SELECT image FROM event WHERE eid=? LIMIT 1' ); //prepare the statement
$stmt->bind_param( 'i',$userId ); //bind our parameter to the statement
$stmt->execute(); //execute statement
$stmt->bind_result( $img ); //were selecting 1 cell (1 column of 1 row), so we can just bind the result to a single var with this line.
$stmt->store_result(); //store our result, so we can see how many rows it returned.
if($stmt->num_rows !== 1){
    http_response_code( 404 ); //image doesnt exist; send 404 status and die.
    die;
}else{
    $stmt->fetch(); //fetch the result of the statement. this populates `$img` for us
    $stmt->close(); //close the prepared statement. 
    header( 'Content-Type: image/png' ); 
    echo base64_decode( $img ); //base64 decode image and echo it.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer. BTW what is the format of the echoed image? I am getting the image to be displayed on the browser, but my ultimate goal is to get this image to be displayed on my android app. There, I'm using an HTTP URL Connection and decoding the stream to a bitmap. I want to know what the format of the stream that is echoed by your code is.

Comment: What format is the stored value? .bmp?, .jpg?  Was it encoded base64 or stored as is?